# how to get result of request leaving website?

Tags: javascript

This is my code for a request when leaving the website:

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return 'Are you sure you want to leave?'
};
```

But now I want to check, if the user really leaves the website or stays there. So, is there any way to check the result of the return or to change the code, so that will work?

Thank you for every answer!

Comment: `setTimeout(youAreStillThere, 1000)` ...

Comment: I don't think that you really need to check as if the user leaves, your code will not execute.

Comment: `unload`, method fires after current page is close, but it also fire on other methods that goes to another page, like changing the URL, pressing back etc

Comment: I just want to run the code, if the player leaves. It's about leaving the client (Logout).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, I just have to put the code for the leaving under the return:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return 'Are you sure you want to leave?'
    console.log("leave website")
};
```

So if the user clicks cancel, it won't be locked in this example, because the website will close before it can lock it.

Comment: maybe it won't be able to finish the log or what ever is written below the return, but I think, it's the best option.